# How to populate the radio div after ajax response?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Html Div where I want to append my html inside this:

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="border:1px solid green;height: 20px;"id="eng_skills"></div>
```

jQuery and AJAX code here. Response contains the HTML which I want to append inside my upper html:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var jobid=$("#eng_jobtitle").val();
   var worker_id=$("#worker_id").val();
   //alert(jobid);
   //alert(worker_id);
    $.ajax({

          type: 'POST',
          url: '/admin/listing-details/get_skills',
          data: {
                "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                "job_title_id" :jobid,
                "worker_id" : worker_id
          },
          success: function (response)
           {

             html+='<div class="form-group">';
             html+='<span class="col-md-6 col-xs-12  no-padding set_text">';
             $.each(response,function(i,val){
              html+='<label class="">'+val.skill_eng+'</label></span>';
              html+='<input type="radio"  name="'+ i +'" id="'+ i +'"/>';


             })
             html+='<span class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 set_text">';
             html+='<input type="radio" name="cooking"><label class="">Yes</label>';
             html+='<input type="radio" name="cooking"><label class="">No</label>';
             html+='</span>';
             html+='</div>';
            $('#eng_skills').html(html);

           }
  })
})
```

Ajax which I'm getting is:

```
{"status":true,
"result":
    [
{"id":1,"job_id":1,"skill_eng":"cleaning","skill_arb":"\u062a\u0646\u0638\u064a\u0641","ordering":1,"added_date":"2018-01-31 00:00:00"},   
     {"id":2,"job_id":1,"skill_eng":"cooking","skill_arb":"\u062a\u0646\u0638\u064a\u0641","ordering":2,"added_date":"2018-01-31 00:00:00"},      
     {"id":3,"job_id":1,"skill_eng":"utensils washing","skill_arb":"\u0623\u0648\u0627\u0646\u064a \u0627\u0644\u063a\u0633\u064a\u0644","ordering":3,"added_date":"2018-01-31 00:00:00"},
     {"id":4,"job_id":1,"skill_eng":"cloths washing","skill_arb":"\u063a\u0633\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0644\u0627\u0628\u0633","ordering":4,"added_date":"2018-01-31 00:00:00"}
]
}
```

After creating my response I am not able to generate my input type radio as I want. It's not appending on the html, why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the array you are looping on is wrong

operate on response['result']

As

```
$.each(response['result'],function(i,val)){
     //code inside
 })
```

also define var html = ''; in the starting

Comment: define var html = ' ';

Answer (score 1):

You must iterate over `response.result`.

`$.each(response.result,function(i,val){`